# Performance issue with psycopg2 named cursor in python

Tags: python, postgresql, database-migration, data-migration

After some research done, I found out the nameless cursor in python using psycopg2 will try to load all the result set into my computer memory, this is a big issue for me as the Postgresql table that I am querying is about 1.4 TB in size. I found out that giving a name to my cursor will create a server-side cursor that will only load the number of rows I will ask it to, using 'fetchmany' but it has become significantly slower to perform a query. Is there a way for me to speed up the server side cursor? 
*I try and only load about 2,000 rows as that is about the size that I need the batches to be in.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% positive if this will fix your performance issue, but you do not need to use `cursor.fetchmany()` with a server-side cursor. You can just iterate over a named cursor.

```
with psycopg2.connect(db_uri_string) as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor(name='cursor_name')
    cursor.itersize = 20000

    query = "SELECT * FROM ..."
    cursor.execute(query)

    for row in cursor:
        # process row
```

Also the lower your itersize, the more network calls are made and that may be slowing down your performance especially with such a large dataset and such a low itersize. If you need to work in batches of 2000 you can increase your itersize and do 2000 rows per fetchmany e.g. `fetchmany(2000)`. fetchmany will not make a network call until it has iterated through all of the current rows fetched.

If itersize is 20000, and you call `fetchmany(2000)`, it would take 10 `fetchmany(2000)` to make a network call.

Comment: may I ask if that also works for views? I am asking, cause it does not seem to work?!? My for loop start immediately with your solution when the traget of my `SELECT` is a `TABLE`, but will take forever when it's a `VIEW`.